# CoreData crashing (object cannot be nil)

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm receiving this crash:

```
Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
*** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: managedObjectContext)
```

I'm trying to find out the cause of this. I'm not sure where this happens and the root cause. Anyone can help? here is the crash log:

```
Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x19058e1c0 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x18efc855c objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x19046f79c -[__NSCFNumber hash]
3  CoreData                       0x19290b13c -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _createAndPostChangeNotification:deletions:updates:refreshes:deferrals:wasMerge:]
4  CoreData                       0x192883340 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _processRecentChanges:]
5  CoreData                       0x19287bc30 _performRunLoopAction
6  CoreFoundation                 0x19053b7dc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
7  CoreFoundation                 0x19053940c __CFRunLoopDoObservers
8  CoreFoundation                 0x19053989c __CFRunLoopRun
9  CoreFoundation                 0x190468048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
10 GraphicsServices               0x191eee198 GSEventRunModal
11 UIKit                          0x1964542fc -[UIApplication _run]
12 UIKit                          0x19644f034 UIApplicationMain
13 MyApp                        0x10013ff88 main (main.m:15)
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x18f44c5b8 (Missing)
```

And here is how the code for CoreData creation:

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    if (appDelegate.managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return appDelegate.managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        appDelegate.managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [appDelegate.managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    }
    return appDelegate.managedObjectContext;
}

// Returns the managed object model for the application.
// If the model doesn't already exist, it is created from the application's model.
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
    @try {
        if (appDelegate.managedObjectModel != nil) {
            return appDelegate.managedObjectModel;
        }
        NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"AppDatabase" withExtension:@"momd"];
        appDelegate.managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    } @catch (NSException *exception) {
        LogError(self, NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), @"EXCEPTION!\n\n%@", exception);
    }
    return appDelegate.managedObjectModel;
}

// Returns the persistent store coordinator for the application.
// If the coordinator doesn't already exist, it is created and the application's store added to it.
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    @try {
        if (appDelegate.persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
            return appDelegate.persistentStoreCoordinator;
        }

        NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:VERSION_SQLITEDB];

        NSError *error = nil;
        appDelegate.persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];

        if (![appDelegate.persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                                  configuration:nil
                                                            URL:storeURL
                                                        options:@{NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption:@YES, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption:@YES}
                                                          error:&error]) {

            if (error) {
                LogError(self, NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), @"ERROR!\n\n%@", error);

                CustomAlertView *alertView = [[CustomAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:ERRORMESSAGE_APPERROR delegate:nil twoButtonView:NO];
                [alertView show];
            }
        }
    } @catch (NSException *exception) {
        LogError(self, NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), @"EXCEPTION!\n\n%@", exception);
    }
    return appDelegate.persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Here is where I think the crash happens, its while I'm getting NSManagedObjectContext reference:

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContextRef {
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator* coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    NSManagedObjectContext* context;
    @try {
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
        [context setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    }
    } @catch (NSException *exception) {
        LogError(self, NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), @"EXCEPTION!\n\n%@", exception);
    }
    return context;
}
```

Would this help?

Comment: are you sure that your project has AppDatabase.momd file?

Comment: yes...my app has this file

Comment: What's the reason to recreate the Core Data stack since there is a reference to the stack in `AppDelegate` anyway?

Comment: Whats `VERSION_SQLITEDB` and which line crashes?

Comment: That crash is not happening in that code-- it happens when you're using Core Data, not when you're setting up the Core Data stack. You need to find the code that's causing the crash and post that instead.

Comment: @shallowThought VERSION_SQLITEDB is a constant.

Comment: @TomHarrington i've updated with a function where i think the crash happens. i'm using that function to get the instance of NSManagedObjectContext to perform fetch